# Formal syntax and semantics for Turkish

Tags: syntax, semantics, formal-semantics, turkish

as a student of linguistics and admirer of Turkish, I wondered whether there are good introductory books for formal syntax and (Montague) semantics for Turkish. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you considered any of the books by GL Lewis?